# ORACLE Join table to select multiple record in 1 row

Tags: database, oracle, join

I have 2 tables

**TableA**: Main table with 1 record for each Field called **ID**
**TableB**: Can contain multiple record for field called **ID**

I want to select everything based on **ID** from **TableA** and **TableB** in 1 line for the end result

Example

Sample Records
From **TableA**

```
ID   Name Address
---  ---- ----------
1    Jack 123 blahST
2    John 234 blahAVE
321  Sam  2123 blahWay
```

From **TableB**

```
ID AccNO
-- -------------
1  12345
1  345345
1  443453
2  99999
3  88888
3  77777
```

End Result should be like

```
Select TableA.ID,
       TableA.Name,
       TableA.Address,
       TableB.ID,
       TableB.AccNO1,
       TableB.AccNO2, --if it exist
       TableB.AccNO3, --if it exist
       TableB.AccNO4, --if it exist MAX
From TableA Full Outer Join TableB on TableB.ID = TableA.ID

TableA.ID  TableA.Name TableA.Address TableB.ID TableB.AccNO TableB.AccNO2 TableB.AccNo3,TableB.AccNo4
---------  ----------- -------------- --------- ------------ ------------- ------------- -------------
 1         Jack        123 Blahst       1        12345        345345        443453              
 2         John        234 BlahAVE      2        99999
 3         Sam         2123 Blahway     3        88888        7777777
```

Comment: Is this for a MySQL or an Oracle database? These are two different DBMS platforms - please amend the tags as appropriate. Also, is there only ever a maximum of 4 account numbers?

Comment: Sorry oracle. I have fixed it. I would say Max would be 5 in very rare case most of the time it is 2 or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways of doing it - one using the PIVOT keyword available in 11g and above, the other using the old-style pivot using MAX() and group by.

Method 1:

```
with tablea as (select 1 id, 'Jack' name, '123 blahST' address from dual union all
                select 2 id, 'John' name, '234 blahAVE' address from dual union all
                select 3 id, 'Sam' name, '2123 blahWay' address from dual),
     tableb as (select 1 id, 12345 accno from dual union all
                select 1 id, 345345 accno from dual union all
                select 1 id, 443453 accno from dual union all
                select 2 id, 99999 accno from dual union all
                select 3 id, 88888 accno from dual union all
                select 3 id, 77777 accno from dual),
      b_res as (select *
                from   (select id,
                               accno,
                               row_number() over (partition by id order by accno) rn
                        from   tableb)
                pivot  (max(accno)
                        for rn in (1 as accno1,
                                   2 as accno2,
                                   3 as accno3,
                                   4 as accno4,
                                   5 as accno5)))
select ta.id ta_id,
       ta.name ta_name,
       ta.address ta_address,
       tb.id tb_id,
       tb.accno1 tb_accno1,
       tb.accno2 tb_accno2,
       tb.accno3 tb_accno3,
       tb.accno4 tb_accno4,
       tb.accno5 tb_accno5
from   tablea ta
       inner join b_res tb on ta.id = tb.id;

     TA_ID TA_NAME TA_ADDRESS        TB_ID  TB_ACCNO1  TB_ACCNO2  TB_ACCNO3  TB_ACCNO4  TB_ACCNO5
---------- ------- ------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Jack    123 blahST            1      12345     345345     443453                      
         2 John    234 blahAVE           2      99999                                            
         3 Sam     2123 blahWay          3      77777      88888
```

Method 2:

```
with tablea as (select 1 id, 'Jack' name, '123 blahST' address from dual union all
                select 2 id, 'John' name, '234 blahAVE' address from dual union all
                select 3 id, 'Sam' name, '2123 blahWay' address from dual),
     tableb as (select 1 id, 12345 accno from dual union all
                select 1 id, 345345 accno from dual union all
                select 1 id, 443453 accno from dual union all
                select 2 id, 99999 accno from dual union all
                select 3 id, 88888 accno from dual union all
                select 3 id, 77777 accno from dual),
      b_res as (select id,
                       max(case when rn = 1 then accno end) accno1,
                       max(case when rn = 2 then accno end) accno2,
                       max(case when rn = 3 then accno end) accno3,
                       max(case when rn = 4 then accno end) accno4,
                       max(case when rn = 5 then accno end) accno5
                from   (select id,
                               accno,
                               row_number() over (partition by id order by accno) rn
                        from   tableb)
                group by id)
select ta.id ta_id,
       ta.name ta_name,
       ta.address ta_address,
       tb.id tb_id,
       tb.accno1 tb_accno1,
       tb.accno2 tb_accno2,
       tb.accno3 tb_accno3,
       tb.accno4 tb_accno4,
       tb.accno5 tb_accno5
from   tablea ta
       inner join b_res tb on ta.id = tb.id;

     TA_ID TA_NAME TA_ADDRESS        TB_ID  TB_ACCNO1  TB_ACCNO2  TB_ACCNO3  TB_ACCNO4  TB_ACCNO5
---------- ------- ------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Jack    123 blahST            1      12345     345345     443453                      
         2 John    234 blahAVE           2      99999                                            
         3 Sam     2123 blahWay          3      77777      88888
```

Comment: Total Genius man, Very easy to understand your solution. I never used `pivot` function before. I really want to thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, one question, in first method, under in temp table `b_res` if I have a join in that query it throws error for pivot max. can you plz help `ORA-00904: tableb.accno: invalid identifier` my query is changed to `pivot  (max(tableb.accno)`

Comment: You should raise this as a new question, and post all relevant information, including sample input and expected output data.

Comment: it would be very tough to explain this again. :(

Comment: Really? You know have three tables, plus an existing statement that you need to amend. Is it really that hard to copy and paste data? Or even a link to this question? Trying to work out your new requirements via comments is going to be impossible.

Comment: nvm, I figured it out. I'll give +1 for your time and your help in past. this is great solution.